# How to import Vietnamese characters with MapInfo Pro?

Tags: mapinfo, internationalization

How can I import shapefiles, Charset "UTF-8" with Vietnamese characters (f.e. "Đường nhựa") correctly?

With UTF-8 I get something like "___ng nh_a"!

Should I use another charset or is it just not possible with MapInfo? QGIS works fine with the same shapefile.

Comment: A similar question was asked [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mapinfo-l/xMVF5OnhE4Y/aqXUytGFpEQJ) where it is said that Vietnamese is supported. Hopefully others can advise.

Comment: What locale are you using on your computer? You could try to start MapInfo Pro using AppLocale and specify a vietnamese locale

Comment: It's a german installation of MapInfo Pro. AppLocale sounds good. I will try this next week and report about it. Thank you!

Comment: I just installed AppLocale. First I had to figure out that the vietnamese language can be selected with „tiếng Việt“. Then I imported vietnamese names again, but unfortunately not really successful. See   [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pj5jJ.png